# I want to check that an exception is thrown, but an error occurs

Tags: kotlin

I can't catch exception

My test:

```
@Test
fun shouldException()  {
    assertThrows<WrongArgumentsException> {
        val request = HttpEntity<String>("{\"username\": \"example\", \"password\": \"12345\"")
        val responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:$port/api/user/registration", request, String::class.java)
    }
}
```

Exception in my method:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    throw WrongArgumentsException(bindingResult.allErrors[0].defaultMessage)
}
```

IN DEBUG:

```
2020-06-05 17:39:43.214 DEBUG 11308 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [com.example.utils.exceptions.basic.WrongArgumentsException: Password should be from 6 to 32 length]
```

there is an exception! But there is error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected com.example.utils.exceptions.basic.WrongArgumentsException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your postForEntity() call is asynchronous, and the test does not wait for the result of the call.

To check, you could replace the call to postForEntity() with directly throwing the exception. Then the assertion in the test will be met.